# Объект в массив JSON

Tags: php, массивы, json

Есть 30 input-ов, из них получается массив PHP, передаю его по $_POST и кодирую в JSON:

```
{"PhoneContact": "123",
"ProductOrder":
              {
              "ProductName": "PHONE",
              "BrandName": "Phone 123",
              "Modification": "S15",
              "Quantity": "1",
              "ProductPrice": "123",
              "ShippingPrice": "123"}
}
```

Надо взять объект `ProductOrder` и поместить в массив:

```
{"PhoneContact": "123",
"ProductOrder":
              [{
              "ProductName": "PHONE",
              "BrandName": "Phone 123",
              "Modification": "S15",
              "Quantity": "1",
              "ProductPrice": "123",
              "ShippingPrice": "123"}]
}
```

Решил так:

```
$arr = array (
"PhoneContact" => ($_POST["PhoneContact"]),
"ProductOrder" => [($_POST["ProductOrder"])]
);
$a = json_encode($arr);
```

Может есть более рациональное решение, если объектов будет не 2, а 100?

Comment: `obj.productOrder = [obj.productOrder];`? Впрочем, вопрос не очень понятен.

Comment: Не нужно делать нерабочий сниппет.